# MySQL: Importing databases from older version

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump

I'm in the process of moving everything from a very old production server to a new one. I'm now trying to copy the MySQL database over to the new system. I have very limited knowledge of MySQL, BTW. First some version info:

Old server:

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.32, for pc-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2
```

New server:

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

On the old server, I made a dump of all databases first:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

Then on the new server, I imported the databases with:

```
mysql -u root -p < all_databases.sql
```

But now, when I try to run mysql, I get an error:

```
$ mysql
ERROR 1275 (HY000): Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'root'@'localhost' has a password in the old format; please change the password to the new format
```

So apparently it has overwritten the user database as well (I really had no idea that would happen, but, you know, limited MySQL knowledge...).

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Temporarily disable `secure-auth` mode, import data, alter the password for `'root'@'localhost'` using default securing method, then enable `secure-auth` mode back.

Comment: Ouch!  That's 8 major releases.  Good luck.  (But it is good to move forward.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing out @Akina's suggestion:

1. Edit your MariaDB server options file, which I think is it at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Debian. In the `[mysqld]` section, add this line: `secure_auth=OFF`
2. Restart MariaDB server: `systemctl restart mariadb` (assuming you have systemd)
3. You should now be able to log in using the `mysql` client and run something like: `SET PASSWORD = password('your_new_password');` Alternatively, run `mysql_secure_installation` from the command-line.
4. Edit the MariaDB server options file again and remove the line you inserted before, then restart the MariaDB server, and everything should be working, hopefully.